# is clojure open to whatever works regarding naming conventions (of fns), especially regarding generic-like fns as partials

Tags: clojure, coding-style, conventions

I'm quite new to functional programming and clojure. I like it.
I'd like to know what the community thinks about following fn-naming approach:
Is it a feasible way to go with such naming, or is it for some reason something to avoid?

Example:

```clj
(defn coll<spec>?
  "Checks wether the given thing is a collection of elements of ::spec-type"
  [spec-type thing]
  (and (coll? thing)
       (every? #(spec/valid? spec-type %)
               thing)))

(defn coll<spec>?nil
  "Checks if the given thing is a collection of elements of ::spec-type or nil"
  [spec-type thing]
  (or (nil? thing)
      (coll<spec>? spec-type thing)))
```

now ... somewhere else I'm using partial applications in clojure defrecrod/specs ...
similar to this:

```clj
; somewhere inside a defrecord
^{:spec (partial p?/coll<spec>?nil ::widgets)} widgets component-widgets
```

now, I created this for colls, sets, hash-maps with a generic-like form for specs (internal application of spec/valid? ...) and with a direct appication of predicates and respectively a <p> instead of the <spec>

currently I'm discussing with my colleagues wether this is a decent and meaningful and useful approach - since it is at least valid to name function like this in clojure - or wether the community thinks this is rather a no-go.

I'd very much like your educated opinions on that.

Comment: I guess I'm curious why you wouldn't use actual Specs for these instead, since `clojure.spec` already supports various collection-type Specs.

Comment: I'd probably also recommend reading at least the Naming chapter of Elements of Clojure, in particular the function section: https://leanpub.com/elementsofclojure/read_sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weird naming convention, but a lot of projects use weird naming conventions because their authors believe they help. I imagine if I read your codebase, variable naming conventions would probably not be the thing that surprises me most. This is not an insult: every project has some stuff that surprises me.

But I don't see why you need these specific functions at all. As Sean Corfield says in a comment, there are good spec combinator functions to build fancier specs out of simpler ones. Instead of writing `coll<spec>?`, you could just combine `s/valid?` with `s/coll-of`:

```
(s/valid? (s/coll-of spec-type) thing)
```

Likewise you can use `s/or` and `nil?` to come up with `coll<spec>?nil`.

```
(s/valid? (s/or nil? (s/coll-of spec-type) thing))
```

This is obviously more to write at each call site than a mere `coll<spec>?nil`, so you may dismiss my advice. But the point is you can extract functions for defining these specs, and use those specs.

```
(defn nil-or-coll-of [spec]
  (s/or nil? (s/coll-of spec)))

(s/valid? (nil-or-coll-of spec-type) thing)
```

Importantly, this means you could pass the result of `nil-or-coll-of` to some other function that expects a spec, perhaps to build a larger spec out of it, or to try to conform it. You can't do that if all your functions have `s/valid?` baked into them.

Think in terms of composing general functions, not defining a new function from scratch for each thing you want to do.